# Is it legal to upload NASA's SRTM dataset to kaggle?

Tags: data-protection, data-ownership

**Short Version:**
Is it legal to upload NASA's SRTM dataset to kaggle.com?

**Long Version:**
I'm doing a computer science and data science project on landslide analysis. For this, I'm considering a variety of features, including slope patterns. To computer slope I'm using NASA's
SRTM (Shuttle Radar Topography Mission) global elevation dataset.

You can find this dataset here: https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/
However the process of downloading this data is a bit messy/unorganized. Therefore there are many sites such as the following two which make the process of doing this easier such as the following two

- http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm
- https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/

I want to download the data and then upload it to kaggle.com, a data science hub. Is this legal? I would assume so since anyone can download NASA's SRTM dataset, but I've not many people provide the datasets for download through other websites.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate question and I've provided details and context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FAQ page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/resources/faqs/#am-i-allowed-to-reuse-lp-daac-data) linked from the site listed in the question says

> **Does NASADEM have restrictions on reuse, sale, or redistribution?**

> NASADEM does not have restrictions on reuse, sale, or redistribution. However, users of NASADEM products are encouraged to cite the product. A Citation Generator is available on each NASADEM DOI Landing Page.

...

> **Am I allowed to reuse LP DAAC data?**

> All data distributed by the LP DAAC contain no restrictions on the data reuse.

It also says that "NASADEM is derived from Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) raw data"

Thus it seems that no restrictions are placed on reuse or **redistribution**. That should include uploading the data to another site. Giving proper attribution and source credit may not be required, but would in my view be advisable.